# Bean class is not specified when using DefaultConfigurationBuilder

Tags: java, properties, apache-commons, xml-configuration

I have used DefaultConfigurationBuilder try to integrated my properties and xml file as below code:

```
DefaultConfigurationBuilder dcfb = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
File file = new File(filePath);
System.out.println(file.getName());
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
dcfb.setFile(new File(filePath));
config = dcfb.getConfiguration(true);
```

And the xml file is looks like as below where the application.properties is the properties file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <properties fileName="application.properties"/>
</configuration>
<PropertyList>
    <Property>
        <Name>CommandTimeout</Name>
        <Value>60</Value>
        <Description>Setting the timeout(in seconds)</Description>
        <DefaultValue></DefaultValue>
    </Property>
    <Property>
        <Name>Address</Name>
        <Value>${server.IP}</Value>
        <Description>ip:port</Description>
        <DefaultValue></DefaultValue>
    </Property>
</PropertyList>
```

But I got the exception when calling getConfiguration(true);

```
org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: 

org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: Bean class is not specified!
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.createConfigurationAt(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:860)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.initCombinedConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:719)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:622)
    at manage.utility.XMLProperty.<init>(XMLProperty.java:32)
    at manage.utility.WebMapLicenseKeyListener.contextInitialized(WebMapLicenseKeyListener.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: Bean class is not specified!
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:395)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:412)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:426)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder.createConfigurationAt(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:855)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: Bean class is not specified!
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:395)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:412)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.initBean(BeanHelper.java:226)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.DefaultBeanFactory.initBeanInstance(DefaultBeanFactory.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder$ConfigurationBuilderProvider.initBeanInstance(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:1763)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.DefaultBeanFactory.createBean(DefaultBeanFactory.java:64)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder$ConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:1066)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder$ConfigurationBuilderProvider.getConfiguration(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:1729)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultConfigurationBuilder$ConfigurationBeanFactory.createBean(DefaultConfigurationBuilder.java:1321)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:390)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationRuntimeException: Bean class is not specified!
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.fetchBeanClass(BeanHelper.java:484)
    at org.apache.commons.configuration.beanutils.BeanHelper.createBean(BeanHelper.java:390)
    ... 25 more
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in each Property tag the attribute config-class specifing the class that map the configuration:

```
<Property config-class="FullQulifiesNameOfPropertyClass">
```